# My question turns blank when I try to edit it

Tags: bug

My question can be found here: [Restore magento quote after payment was refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260706/get-magento-quote-after-payment-was-refused)

Whenever I click on the edit button, the whole question turns blank. This does not happen with other questions that I have written.

## Before Clicking on Edit

[image: Before Edit]

## After Clicking on Edit

[image]

## Update:

The bug just disappeared when I open a new tab with that same link.
However, even if I refresh the first tab with `F5` and try to edit the post, the post still turns blank.

Comment: Works fine for me. Tried clearing your cache? What's in your browser's console? What's your browser/OS?

Comment: Latest firefox (38.0), Xubuntu 15.04, I get nothing in the browser's console.

Comment: Did you clear your cache?

Comment: Even after clearing my cache, the site doesn't work on the first tab, but does on the second one (see update)

Comment: Well, close that tab.

Comment: @Mat yes sure, I just wanted to report that bug so that it doesn't come up in the future. In that tab, I get the error `Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/.
full.en...f672a89 (line 1)`

Comment: If it works on other tabs, and works for others, bug's most likely on your side, not SE's.

Comment: You seem to have problems with the inline editor. Then use good old non-inline one: ctrl-click "edit".

Comment: Can you reproduce this with no plugins or extensions?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce it at all. It happened on one random tab I had opened, and I couldn't even reproduce the bug in an other tag on that same browser (Firefox)